# Cucumber & Vim: Getting around incorrect syntax highlighting for steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, cucumber

One thing I've often noticed with cucumber is the syntax highlighting for steps such as:

```
Given /^I have a category with name "([^"]*)"$/ do |category|
...
end
```

Vim fails to escape the " inside the regex call, and consequently everything after the third " is highlighted as if part of a string. This make it difficult to pick up typos/incorrect methods and half my steps file ends up a (rather unhelpful) shade of red.

So...anyone know of any plugins which can correctly interpret those sorts of steps, and/or an elegant way to rewrite them that doesn't throw off syntax highlighting?

Cheers...

Comment: Are you using something like https://github.com/tpope/vim-cucumber/ or just the default highlighting that comes with vim?

Comment: rails.vim & cucumber.vim are both installed

Comment: A screenshot might help here. I don't see this problem in vim 7.2 on OS X. I'm using rails.vim, but not cucumber.vim. Maybe uninstall the later and see if that's where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is solved with current versions of vim-cucumber and related packages.  I do not see what you are saying, using the latest versions of

- vim-cucumber
- vim-rails
- Vim